# Copy list of strings to another list of strings

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my simple class:

```
public class Friends
{
  public Friends()
  {
    Myfriend = new List<string>();
    Share = new List<bool>();
  }
  public List<string> Myfriend { get; set; }
  public List<bool> Share { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class i want to pass into my view. Before I do that I would like to "fill" up

```
public List<string> Myfriend { get; set; }
```

With the values i have in another list of strings.

var listofUsersFriends <--- This list contains a bunch of names(strings).

Can I assign the values i a way similar to this:

```
var model = new Friends();
foreach (var item in listofUsersFriends)
{
  //Add list items
}
```

I'm totally stuck, feel free to give advice on other ways of solving this =)
Thanks!

EDIT: The end goal is to pass a model to my view containing a list friend-objects.
Like this:
Bob      CheckboxShare
Wouter   CheckboxShare
ETC..

This seems to send a model with two separate strings, i.e the checkbox is not related to the friend. I know I have messed up somewhere but i do not understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Add each item individually to the list in your `foreach` like this:

  model.Friends.Add(item);
- Initialize a new list based on your `listofUsersFriends` :

  model.Friends = new List(listofUsersFriends);
- Add a range of items in one go:

  model.Friends.AddRange(listofUsersFriends);

**Update**

To link the booleand and string field together you can declare a class that defines your data:

```
public class FriendStatus
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked get; set; }
}
```

And then change your view model to have a list of `FriendStatus`.

Comment: Hmm, I still have som trouble, would you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: thank you! I will try with this and get back to accept!